# how to disable redis rdb persistence in redis5.0

Tags: redis

I have tried the search result, like modify redis.conf, change the appendonly to no,
comment save 900 1 etc, add save "" .but still not work, how to do?

Comment: Commenting out the `save` and `dir` should be sufficient - why do you think rdb persistence is still enabled?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the problem?